# What is the appropriate Stack Exchange to ask about software scheme

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I have some questions about the logic of a program that I am coding, my questions is not about pattern or code, but program design and algorithm.
In fact I am not sure my algorithm can give to me a robust solution or a valid one; so I desire to ask if someone would see some caveats in my logics.

Which is the best place for this kind of question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have some questions about the logic of a program that I am coding, my questions is not about pattern or code, but program design and algorithm.

According to [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour), the site's goals and objectives are (from ***Help → Take the tour...***):

> Programmers Stack Exchange is [for ... people] who are interested in
>   getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software
>   development.

I think there's a strong intersection between conceptual concepts and design, and conceptual concepts and algorithm selections, so it looks like its on-topic from 10,000 feet. That is, the question passes the "sniff test".

Diving in a little deeper [under on-topic-ness](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) (from ***Help → Detailed answers...***):

> - software requirements
> - software architecture and design
> - ...

So it appears to be specifically called out as on-topic.

---

> In fact I am not sure my algorithm can give to me a robust solution or a valid one; so I desire to ask if someone would see some caveats in my logics.

So this could be a question more appropriate for a different site, like [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The same exercise repeated for Code Review follows....

According to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), the site's goals and objectives are (from ***Help → Take the tour...***):

> Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.

So NO, your question does not appear to pass the sniff test, so its not appropriate for Code Review SE.

You should not investigate this path any further.

---

**Takeaway**: you should ask on  [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (keeping in mind how the question should be framed to promote the site's goals); and not ask on other sites like  [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `You should not investigate this path any further.` is this written in sarcasm font?

Comment: Calvin - no, no sarcasm. CR.SE states its goals and objectives are peer review of code. Skary is not interested in that (and probably does not have a working implementation). So he should stay away from CR.SE unless he has working implementation and wants it reviewed.

Comment: it just read like your overall suggestion was not to investigate developing software any further.

Comment: Calvin - oh, my bad. No, I was not advocating that. I better get that fixed.

Comment: oh I know, I just got back from lunch and im killing time. made me chuckle.